# Use Ajax ToolKitScriptManager along with ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a page test.aspx which is inheriting master page.The master page has script manager addeded to it.I am trying to add the ***rating control*** availabel in the ajax control toolkit.

So i need to add the line `<Ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>`

But since the script manager is already availabel in master page i cannot add this line to my test page.And if i dont add it will not function.

What should i do?

Is there difference between `script manager` and `toolkitscriptmanager`.

How to use both simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the scriptManager in the master page with `<Ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>` .This will certainly solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you use ASP.NET 3.5 and controls from AJAX Control Tookit then you must use the ToolkitScriptManager, rather than the ASP.NET ScriptManager. This limitation according to the fact that toolkit script manager adds updated Ajax scripts and without that most of the controls from Ajax Control toolkit library will not work.

If you using ASP.NET 4.0 (4.5) than you have choice to use ScriptManager or ToolkitScriptManager.

Basically the main feature of the ToolkitScriptManager is that it can combine js resource added to page using ScriptReference collection. These js files should be embedded to assembly and for this Assembly ScriptCombine assembly attribute should be added. The main problem here is that you can't control how scripts are combined and after you will try to combine your own scripts you can have a lot of problems (I had experience using this feature and as a result we rejected combining of our scripts using this approach).

The main point here is that currently standard script manager has ability to combine scripts using composite script collection.